# HtmlImage not displaying

Tags: javascript, css

I have a asp.net page with a div. In the div there are two htmlimages. The size of the images are A4.

I can only get one image to display on the page. The second image is rendered but not displayed. When I change the first image to display:none the second one is shows up. Also, when I set the outer div's height to a small size, I can see both images but I need it in full size.

Any ideas how to get the page to display both images?

Comment: Code? Css? Seems like an issue with css, this has probably nothing to do with asp.net, nor html.

Comment: I can bet you have an `overflow: hidden` in your CSS somewhere that is hiding the CSS when they are bigger than the screen size. Normally two A4 images should display just fine.

Comment: Thanks. Found overflow: hidden. I removed it and both images are displayed. Now when I do window.print, I still get only the first image. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nunespascal wrote I Found overflow: hidden. I removed it and both images are displayed